Docker Error: Load Metadata For Docker.io/library/swift:5.9
I'm attempting to dockerize a vapor server. I'm on a Mac M1, hoping to use the docker image on Ubuntu 22.04 server. I get an error when trying to build (see below in the picture). Any ideas on why I'm getting an error for "load metadata for docker.io/library/swift:5.9-ja"
Do I need to downgrade my swift version to 5.9 (currently 5.10)?


Hi, you are more likely to get help if you include the error information as text instead of an image.

You can see the error in the log - error getting credentials. You might need to log into your Docker account to allow it to pull down the image
